How to install libncurses.so.5 for ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to use STM32 Cube IDE for ARM controllers, which uses arm-none-eabi-gdb. This is dependent on libncurses.so.5. I am not able to find how to install it on Ubuntu 24.04.
Can anyone please guide me what to do?
Is it possible to build libncurses.so.5 on my laptop?

Why not just make a link of libncurses.so.5 to libncurses.so.6.4 ?

libncurses.so.5 is also needed for Android RenderScript development (llvm-rs-cc needs it to compile RenderScript files)

For Ubuntu 24 add to source list and then install:

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-focal-sources.list


sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386



I tried the suggest link via ln -s as per comment in original question but failed the same, the above fixed the issue for me

For my case, adding the given source and installing libncurses5 (not libncurses5:i386) made it.

Unfortunately, the versions offered are for Debian 12 which does not align with Ubuntu 24.04 which is based on Debian 13.
https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html
What Debian version are the different Ubuntu versions based on?
Trying to fix this with different library versions compiled in parallel is likely to cause more trouble in the long run even if you do manage to get it to work for a short time.
Is there are chance of the supplier getting out a new version based on Debian 13 in the near future? Worth checking.
My recommended options

Install a version of Ubuntu 22.04 along side your 24.04 with a common /home (This illustrates the benefits or running an old & new Ubuntu OS side-by-side when you are using third party software locked to a particular version. You keep the old going until all features are available in the new.)

Install a Windows versions under WINE. This tends to be somewhat
tricky at best but possibly might work. If you do have trouble it is
likely with programming targets.

Install a Flatpack version.
https://www.feaser.com/en/blog/2021/01/install-stm32cubeide-on-linux-as-a-flatpak/
This site looks promising although I don't know much about flatpack
myself I have heard that some people like it. It is based on installing everything complete a bit like snap.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-flatpak-on-ubuntu


Sorry I can't me more helpful with this but good luck with whatever you decide.

What i did on my Ubuntu 24 Install :-

get into /etc/apt/sources.list.d and locate ubuntu.sources.
open the terminal in that directory by right clicking in it.
then run sudo pluma ./ubuntu.sources a pluma editor will open.
just add these lines:-

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu 
Suites: focal-security
Components: main universe
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


save it and close it.
then in terminal run sudo apt update.
then run sudo apt install libncurses5.

Hopefully that works for you it did for me.
